# How to use a composite key with Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: castle-activerecord

I read that in order to map a class using Castle ActiveRecord
the class must have a primary key (surrogate or composite).

Now, suppose I have a table which I only want to use for reading
and the table doesn't have surrogate key or natural composite key.

Is there any way to be able to still have some manual Guid (or other id) generation
to make it possible to map the class?

Again, the table is used ONLY for reading purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good description of Castle Active Record with Composite Key here:

[Active Records Primary Keys](http://docs.castleproject.org/Active%20Record.Primary%20key%20mapping.ashx)

Note using composite key is not recommended.

How do you plan to select rows from your table if you have no key?